# Does an array in which info is stored in a sub function hold the info in the main function?

Tags: c, arrays

I just want to make sure, if i declare an array in the main.c function or any other function, and pass is to an other function which stores information into the array. Is the information stored in the array when i use it outside the function I stored the information in?

Comment: outside the function means what? can you elaborat more?

Comment: Are you asking whether passing an array as an argument makes a copy of it? No. In C, passing an array as an argument just passes a pointer. How can you learn C and miss such a fundamental concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple example will clear your doubt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func ( int arr[] )
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       arr[i]=i;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int arr[10],i;

   func(arr);

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes. For example, if we have

```
void foo(unsigned char *buf)
{
    buf[0] = 0;
    buf[1] = 1;
}

void main(void)
{
    unsigned char a[2];

    foo(a); // now a[0] = 0 and a[1] = 1;    
}
```